# What is difference between @api.one, @api.multi and @api.model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am confused regarding `@api.one`, `@api.multi`, and `@api.model` in Odoo.

What are the differences between the three and what are their use cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`api.one` is meant to be used when method is called only on one record. It makes sure, that there are no multiple records when calling method with `api.one` decorator. Let say you got record `partner =  res.partner(1,)`. It is only one record and there is method for example (in `res.partner`):

```
@api.one
def get_name(self):
    return self.name #self here means one record
```

calling it like this works:

```
partner.get_name()
```

But if there would be more records, like `partners = res.partner(1, 2,)`

calling it, would raise a Warning, telling you that you can only call it on one record. For multiple records `api.multi` is used, where `self` is recordset and it can be iterated through all records to do something. For example:

```
@api.multi
def get_partner_names(self):
    names = []
    for rec in self:
        names.append(rec.name)
    return ', '.join(names)
```

And `api.model` is considered to be used when you need to do something with model itself and don't need to modify/check some exact model's record/records. For example there could be method that returns some meta info about model's structure or some helper methods, etc. Also in documentation it is said that this api is good to use when migrating from old api, because it "politely" converts code to new api. Also in my own experience, if you need method to return something, `model` decorator is good for it. `api.one` returns empty list, so it might lead to unexpected behavior when using `api.one` on method when it is supposed to return something.

Some more info: http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorator.html

Comment: No, this is completely wrong... You can call an api.one method on a recordset containing multiple record, it will just loop on the recordset, redefining self for each reacord. See the other answers...

Comment: Also, it does not return empty list, it returns a list of the return value of each operation (which might not work for gui calls if it expects a dict)

Comment: You are right about api.one. I was wrong. At that time of writing I thought it was working like that, but it was not. What I described about api.one, there is actually a method self.ensure_one, which allows one and only one record. It is usually called at the start of method body.

Comment: Indeed. ensure_one only makes sense with `@api.multi` though, it wouldn't do anything with `@api.one`.

Answer (score 5):

- **Difference between one, multi and model**

You actually *can* call an `@api.one`  method with a RecordSet containing multiple records. The only difference is that with `@api.one` the looping on records will be done outside of the function that you define, and as `self` the decorator will pass each record in the RecordSet one by one.

As an example, let's define two functions in our model `example.model`:

```
@api.one
def print_self_one(self):
    print self

@api.multi
def print_self_multi(self):
    print self
```

And let's call them both the following way from [odoo shell](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/9ed13353c0d5f6b8a9684e612514b3b834642554):

```
model = env['example.model']
record_set = model.browse(1,2)
print "record set: " + record_set
print "using @api.one:"
record_set.print_self_one()
print "using @api.multi:"
record_set.print_self_multi()
```

Would return:

```
record set: example.model(1,2)
using @api.one:
example.model(1)
example.model(2)
using @api.multi:
example.model(1,2)
```

Thus, the following two are equivalent:

```
@api.one
_compute_name(self):
    self.name = "Default Name"

@api.multi
print_self_multi(self):
    for record in self:
        record.name = "Default Name"
```

even if thery are called with more record in the recordset.

On the other hand, you do not use *any* decorator, then it can not be called with more (or less) than one record, or it will complain and probably stop with an error.

`@api.model` is a completely different story: you should only use this decorator if you only expect it to be called with an empty recordset.

- **When to use which**

If you expect a non-empty RecordSet as input value, then, in many cases, you can use both `@api.one` and `@api.multi`, it is just a matter of personal preference. I personally prefer to use `@api.one` when it is possible, because I find the code much cleaner that way (also, for compute and onchange methods the Odoo source generally uses `@api.one`).

There are a few cases where you can only use `@api.multi` though:

1. If you not only want to loop on the records, but you would also want to do something only once:

   ```
    @api.multi
    print_self_multi(self):
        print "this will only be  printed once"
        for record in self:
            print "this will be printed len(record_set) times"
   ```
2. If return value is important. A function decorated with `@api.one` will *always* return a list (a list of the return values in your function as iterations). In a number of cases though, especially when interacting with the GUI, you will have to return a dictionary (for example with a warning). In those cases, you will have to go with `@api.multi`.

Answer (score 3):

**api.one**

This decorator loops automatically on Records of RecordSet for you. Self is redefined as current record:

```
@api.one   ## here you will get singleton object in self
def name(self):
    self.name = ’admin’
```

**@api.multi**

Self will be the current RecordSet without iteration. It is the default behavior:

```
@api.multi  ## here you will get multi objects in self
def name(self):
    print len(self)
    for obj in self:
        obj.name = 'Admin'
```

**@api.model**

This decorator will convert old API calls to decorated function to new API signature. It allows to be polite when migrating code.

```
@api.model 
def name(self):
    pass
```

Method decorators needs to be defined according to your methods need, if you want to return dictionary from the method then your method must contains `@api.multi`.

Refer [New API Guideline](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

**@api.multi**

Decorate a record-style method where `self` is a recordset. The methodtypically defines an operation on records. Such a method::

```
@api.multi
def method(self, args):
  ...
```

may be called in both record and traditional styles, like::

```
recs = model.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
recs.method(args)

model.method(cr, uid, ids, args, context=context)
```

**@api.model**

Decorate a record-style method where `self` is a recordset, but its contents is not relevant, only the model is. Such a method::

```
@api.model
def method(self, args):
...
```

may be called in both record and traditional styles, like::

```
recs = model.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
recs.method(args)

model.method(cr, uid, args, context=context)
```

You can find the base code for these decorators in the file: 
*odoo/api.py*