# Value field object inherits empty odoo8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have an object `a` that inherits from object `b`

```
 class b(models.Model):
    x = fields.Char(string="x")
    y = fields.Char(string="y")

 class a(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['b']
    @api.model 
    def method(self, cr, uid, context=None): 
        valueofx=self.x 
        valueofy=self.y
```

I want to access to a value field of the class `b` from class `a`

I'm using this syntax..

```
     valueofx=self.x
     valueofy=self.y
```

The value of x and y is null / None. What's wrong ?

Comment: You're not giving any context to your question, can you show the full code of the method?

Comment: this is the method using the api model 

@api.model
    def method(self, cr, uid, context=None):
     valueofx=self.x
    valueofy=self.y

Comment: `@api.model` doesn't guarantee you have a valid record, you shold read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112660/what-is-different-b-w-api-one-api-multi-and-api-model). You should also edit your question to include the method.

Comment: it works with api multi thnks